# Logical operator in Python

Tags: python, logical-operators

Consider the Python commands:

```
>>> print 3%2 == 0
False
>>> print 3%2 == 1
True
```

The output is completely right. But I read somewhere that:

> Any nonzero number is interpreted as **true**.

Why does `print 2 and 4` return `4`, rather than `True`?

```
>>> print 2 and 4 
4
```

Answer (score 2):

This is from the logical short-cuts that many languages take.  The `and` operator in this case appears in the low-level code as if it were:

```
a = 2
b = 4
return b if a else a
```

... or

```
if not a:
    return a
else:
    return b
```

This works as expected with Boolean values.  With other data types, the result is non-intuitive (until you get used to it).